# Hadoop Installation: Format Namenode

Tags: hadoop

I'm struggling with installing Hadoop 2.2.0 on my Mac OSX 10.9.3. I essentially followed this tutorial:
http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide

When I run `$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format` to format namenode, I get the message:
`SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Macintosh.local/192.168.0.103`. I believe this is preventing me from successfully running the test

```
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-
distributedshell-2.2.0.jar org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.Client --jar 
$HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.2.0.jar --
shell_command date --num_containers 2 --master_memory 1024
```

Does anyone know how to correctly format namenode?

(Regarding the test command above, someone mentioned to me that it could have something to do with the hdfs file system not functioning properly, if this is relevant.)

Comment: You probably started up namenode. You have to format namenode before you can start it up.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, what exactly does "format namenode" entail? Is it like editing the core-site.xml files and such?

Comment: It is similar to a traditional file system getting formatted for the first time. What it does is create the metadata. This is comparable to a traditional file system partition table creation.